# Mac App — date time stamp every mouse click

Tags: macos, mouse, visualization

I want to create a data visualization that maps my mouse clicks through time. To do that, I need to collect data of time stamps for my mouse clicks.

I’m using [Mouse Mile](https://www.pointworks.de/software/mouse-miles/) to total how far my mouse moves, count clicks and keystrokes. However, it just gives me a *total number*.

**Is there an existing application that I can run on Mac in the background that creates a .csv of time stamps every time I click?**

(I understand how I could do this, for example, with JavaScript in a browser, but I want it to be running whenever my computer is awake.)

Thanks all.